# right way of using rosmake?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, rosmake, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In groovy environment I have used `catkin_make` to build my packages most of the time, But I am not clear with use of `rosmake`. I have few packages which use rosmake to build, I have gone through several tutorials and [answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/64472/raspberry-pi-csi-camera-driversupport/) in this forum, still I have not figured out the right way of using rosmake.
below are the steps I followed, for one particular package which uses rosmake:

> ```
> $ mkdir -p ~/rosbuild_ws/
> >     $ cd ~/rosbuild_ws/
> $ rosws init . /opt/ros/groovy
> >     $ svn co http://prairiedog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gencam_cu/
> $ cd gencam_cu/src
> >     $ sudo gedit CMakeList.txt
> ```

and I add `link_directories(/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/)` on the top, I save and exit.

now when I issue

> $ rosmake gencam_cu

I get an Error as shown below:

`... ERROR : No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names`

I have also followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) of using rosbuild with catkin workspace, but then I am able to overcome the above error only to arrive at another error which is as shown below:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/opencv_calib3d  ...`

so, It would be great if someone can list down the steps followed to build a package (for eg. the one mentioned above) with rosmake. Also, please let me know if the steps mentioned above are right? and if I am missing few points here with regard to the build process.

Thanks and best regards,

Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195031/right-way-of-using-rosmake?/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2014-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the package you are using is rosmake, you need to add the package to the workspace in the same way you'd do with `wstool`.

i.e. instead of just `svn co` do `rosws set gencam_cu --svn URL`. Then `rosws update`.
After sourcing the `setup.bash` `roscd`, `rosmake` etc should work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-10-16**:
Hi, Thank you for the quick response, `rosmake` is able to find gencam_cu package but it fails to build because `ld` cannot find opencv libraries and boost libraries. Which is the 2nd error mentioned in the question above... I tried to include opencv libs in CMakeLists but still it fails.

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-10-16**:
I would like to add another point here, the wstool which I have in wheezy was installed through easy_install whereas the one on my pc is the one installed using sudo apt-get, should there be any difference between the 2? as the steps above work well on PC and not on Rpi (wheezy).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-16**:
It might be a later version, but I don't know about that.